# Editing your own answer shows a guide that says "always respect the original author"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Editing your own answer shows a guide that says "always respect the original author". Simple as that. Don't know what else to say about that.

Comment: what's the unexpected state that you are considering to be a "bug"?

Comment: @schroeder If you edit one of your own answer it says "always respect the original author" in the sidebar

Comment: Self-respect is good, right? :-)

Answer (score 3):

This note comes up when anyone edits any answer.

Adding a check in to see if the editor is the OP just adds complexity, and is unneeded.